# Adding a check to php function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got this basic function as below:

```
    function buy()
    {
        $item_id = ( int )$this->uri->segment( 3 );
        if ( $item_id > '0' )
        {
            $item = $this->db->where( 'shop_id', $item_id )->get( 'shop' )->row();
            if ( $item )
            {
                $player = $this->user->info( $this->user->id() );

                    if ( $player->users_money >= $item->shop_req_money && $player->users_credits >= $item->shop_req_credits)
                    {

                    $this->db->update( 'users_items', array( 'users_id' => $this->user->id(), 'users_motors_id' => '0' ), array( 'users_items_id' => $item->users_items_id ) );
                    $this->db->update( 'users', array( 'users_money' => $player->users_money - $item->shop_req_money, 'users_credits' => $player->users_credits - $item->shop_req_credits ), array( 'users_id' => $this->user->id() ) );
                    $this->db->query( 'UPDATE users SET users_money=users_money+' . $item->shop_req_money . ', users_credits=users_credits+' . $item->shop_req_credits . ' WHERE users_id=' . $this->db->escape( $item->shop_users_id ) );
                    $this->db->delete( 'shop', array( 'shop_id' => $item->shop_id ) );
                    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'success', true );

                }
                else
                    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', true );
            }
        }
        header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    }
```

and I edited it like that to add additional check if the reg ip isn't the same as the other one and if so to set an error message.

```
function buy()
{
    $item_id = ( int )$this->uri->segment( 3 );
    if ( $item_id > '0' )
    {
        $item = $this->db->where( 'shop_id', $item_id )->get( 'shop' )->row();
        if ( $item )
        {
            $player = $this->user->info( $this->user->id() );
            $players = $this->user->info( $item->shop_users_id );


                if ( $players->users_reg_ip === $player->users_reg_ip )
                {
                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'errorip', true );
                }
                elseif ( $player->users_money >= $item->shop_req_money && $player->users_credits >= $item->shop_req_credits)
                {

                $this->db->update( 'users_items', array( 'users_id' => $this->user->id(), 'users_motors_id' => '0' ), array( 'users_items_id' => $item->users_items_id ) );
                $this->db->update( 'users', array( 'users_money' => $player->users_money - $item->shop_req_money, 'users_credits' => $player->users_credits - $item->shop_req_credits ), array( 'users_id' => $this->user->id() ) );
                $this->db->query( 'UPDATE users SET users_money=users_money+' . $item->shop_req_money . ', users_credits=users_credits+' . $item->shop_req_credits . ' WHERE users_id=' . $this->db->escape( $item->shop_users_id ) );
                $this->db->delete( 'shop', array( 'shop_id' => $item->shop_id ) );
                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'success', true );

            }
            else
                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', true );
        }
    }
    header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
}
```

**It works the way it is BUT basically I am asking if thats the correct way of doing that or there should be something else I can do similiar to that but better? Would be really appreciated if there any comments on my question. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `check if the reg ip isn't the same as the other one` but inside the condition `$players->users_reg_ip === $player->users_reg_ip`. contradicting, maybe `!==`

Comment: I can directly include it in the elseif statement but in that case it will display same error if he doesnt have credits/money and if he is trying to buy from same ip. So, simply `error` is set to produce error message if the user doesnt have money or credits but I want to add additional error message called `errorip` if he is trying to buy from the same ip, do you understand me what I meant?

Comment: oh okay, since you given the context, i understand now, by the way? is this CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can include that on the condition block. Like this:

```
if ( $players->users_reg_ip === $player->users_reg_ip) {
    // trying to buy from the same IP
    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'errorip', true );
}

elseif ( $player->users_money < $item->shop_req_money && $player->users_credits < $item->shop_req_credits) {
    // if user has not enough money and user credits is less than shop requirement credits
    // or maybe you mean OR ||
    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', true );

}
else {
    $this->db->update('users_items', 
        array( 'users_id' => $this->user->id(), 'users_motors_id' => '0' ), 
        array( 'users_items_id' => $item->users_items_id ) 
    );

    $this->db->update( 'users', 
        array( 'users_money' => $player->users_money - $item->shop_req_money, 
            'users_credits' => $player->users_credits - $item->shop_req_credits 
        ), 
        array( 'users_id' =>  $this->user->id() ) 
    );

    $this->db->query( 'UPDATE users SET users_money=users_money+' . $item->shop_req_money . ', users_credits=users_credits+' . $item->shop_req_credits . ' WHERE users_id=' . $this->db->    escape(     $item->shop_users_id ) );

    $this->db->delete( 'shop', array( 'shop_id' => $item->shop_id ) );
    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'success', true );
}

// instead of using referrer why not
// redirect('controller/method'); ?
```

Comment: Ahh, so I can move the checks in the if statements and the actual database updates in the else statement. Is that safe and valid ? I mean can it be somehow avoided if the user doesnt have money or credits for example and actually purchase something or its totally okay the way it is for sure?

Comment: @MobEn yes should be the logical way, if none of the error conditions are found then, else will execute, thus the update

Comment: so, yeah. its basically the same as the basic one but just a bit different and still it cannot be avoided. I mean people wont be able to buy something without the required credits/money for sure, right?

Comment: @MobEn actually on the elseif block, i think it should have been OR (||) instead of AND (&&), so that either of those two are met, then error triggers

Comment: The elseif block statements are totally okay as they are && in the basic script and it works correctly. Just I am worried after the changes if the else statement with the actual database updates cannot be executed without for sure meeting the above requirements right? I meant its basically as the default function but just moving the checks in the if blocks above the database update elseif. Is that correct and safe one?

Comment: @MobEn just the basic logic here is that, when a considered error is met (on those conditions), it just sets the flash data, if not, then it executes the update. or are you thinking of something else? do you still want to update after a detected error occured?, anyway, why don't you try it?

Comment: No, I don't want to update after a check isn't met for sure. So, basically to sum it up. The above code you provided is the same as my basic one but adding the additional check. I meant is it secure that else database updates cannot be executed without for sure meeting the first 2 checks requirements?

Comment: @MobEn yep, thats basically it. if `the if block and elseif block` are met, then no updates will be made, `ELSE` updates will be made. thats just basic if elseif else logic

Comment: thanks a lot. so this is a better way to do it instead of my first one in the main post right?

Comment: @MobEn yep, definite much better on the context of conditions, the intent is much straightforward, check for errors, if one fails, then set flash error, else execute update

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's much appreciated. The answer is now accepted!